# Laravel connects to the database on every request. How can I stop this?

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 and I noticed that on every page load, laravel tries to connect to the database. You can check for this behaviour by setting invalid credentials for the default database. You'll get an error on every page load, so this means that Laravel tries connect to the database. This even happens on maintenance mode pages.

Why is this? Is there any to stop Laravel from doing this? There's no need to connect to the database on pages that don't query the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Laravel only actually connects to the database the first time the database is needed. Generally, this is the first time you query the database. If you never query the database, it will never attempt to connect to it.

This is a little simplified. You may have some custom code that checks the connection to the database for some reason, and that would require connecting to it, but this is a less common scenario, and you would probably know about it.

If your app is connecting to the database on every page load, that means you're attempting to run a query on every page load. This probably means you have a query being run in a middleware, a service provider, or maybe even your routes file.

If you have debug on, the stacktrace provided by the PDOExecption from your invalid password should point to the query being attempted, as well as where it is being run from.

Comment: You're right! I was using DB::listen in my AppServiceProvider and apparently that forces laravel to connect to the database.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because the way Laravel has been built. Its internal processes are making sure that DB is there when you need it later.

I would do the following:

```
'driver' => 'sqlite',
```

and for the sqlite connection settings

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => ':memory:',
    'prefix' => '',
]
```

That way, it'll use an in-memory database and the database will cease to exist when the database connection is closed, and since you won't be opening a connection, you'll never have a local database open.